# Google-like search of Mongo database

Tags: mongodb, performance, search-engine, database

I am implementing a Mongo database in my Android project.
I will have a base of products (like TV's, printers, etc...) and I want to implement a 
"search by name" feature. But the main problem I'm facing is that I can't find a way to do a search which would give me semi-matches.
I could implement it, but I'm afraid that it will slow down my base.
I wonder if there are any good "Search engines" that work with Mongo?

Comment: Did you look at MongoDB's [text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One product to look at is elastic search. It has some built in features for doing type to find searches.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a limited set of products to search against, your best bet is probably to add metadata to each product that you search against. Enable full text search on your primary name, description and metadata fields. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/